# How to set JavaScript variable by php with out AJAX?

Tags: php, javascript

I need to set JavaScript variable by php variable with out ajax.
I try following code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var url = <?php echo($url); ?>;
</script>
```

but it will make problem,How can I do it?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Url is a string, so put it within quotes:

```
var url = '<?php echo($url); ?>';
```

Comment: Also, You can shorten it by doing this: <?=$url;?>

Comment: @AdamF - Just remember that this is system-dependent. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/200640/are-php-short-tags-acceptable-to-use